# How to programmatically check a Bootstrap button group (radio) button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, buttongroup

http://jsfiddle.net/rphpbqp9/

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary success active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="optionFalse" checked />false
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-sm btn-primary danger">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="optionTrue" />true
    </label>
</div>

$('#optionTrue').button('toggle');
```

I've read more question answers, but none of them works.
The button toggle doesn't work, I tried to add/remove "active" class, doesn't have an effect. I'm using 1.10 jQuery and 3.1 Bootstrap. This supposed to be simple, I'm pulling my hair out!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`button()` needs to be called on the element with the class `btn`...

```
$('#optionTrue').closest('.btn').button('toggle');
```

This will toggle the buttons properly and update the checked properties of each input properly...

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6h3c5axn/)

Comment: You are right sir! Should I maybe put the id to the label then, so I don't have to call 'closest'?

Comment: I wish I asked this question earlier, I'd have more hair left by now.

Comment: I just tried, it works if I move the ids a level up, then I don't have to use closest http://jsfiddle.net/6h3c5axn/1/ , one more thing: the is checked calls don't work then. You can dig down for the child though to get to the input field.

Answer (score 3):

It's crazy the bootstrap docs (3.2) don't make this more obvious, but here's the simplest method I've found to set the initial state of radio buttons in code.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="optionFalse" class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" /> false
    </label>
    <label id="optionTrue" class="btn btn-primary ">
        <input type="radio" name="options" /> true
    </label>
</div>

if (initTrue) {
    $('#optionTrue').button('toggle');
}
else {
    $('#optionFalse').button('toggle');
}
```

After reading dozens of posts on this subject, it seems these are the general points of confusion:

- The **'toggle**' method doesn't toggle between states (off->on->off) as one might expect, but rather just sets the referenced button to "on" and turns all the other buttons "off".
- The id referenced needs to be on the 'label' and not the 'input'.

Comment: The id is on the label? How freaky is that?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/y5qccerz/

```
document.querySelector(".btn-group input[id='optionTrue']").checked = true;
```